# Using Tomee Maven Plugin with Upgraded OpenWebBeans

Tags: maven, events, cdi, apache-tomee, openwebbeans

I'm using the Tomee Maven plugin to develop an app that uses CDI event passing. I am currently not able to fire events that have generic type parameters and, as far as I can tell, this is because the Tomee instance wants to use openwebbeans 1.2.7, which does not support this. I seems that openwebbeans 1.5.0 and upwards do support this but I'm not sure how (or if) I can get the plugin to use this version.

I have tried to use the plugin config to replace the libraries with the new versions, but this leads to further exceptions (no class def, etc.)

The plugin version is:

```
<groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7.3</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache tomee-1.7.x (EE6) is using Apache OpenWebBeans-1.2.x which is a CDI-1.0 specification implementation.

If you are up to using Java EE7 then simply switch to TomEE-7.0.0-M1 which uses the latest openwebbeans-1.6.x version.

Attention: the groupId in maven has changed! It is now org.apache.tomee
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.0-M1/

Comment: Thanks. I'll give feedback when I get a chance to try this out!